# Can't drag an image into a new Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave

I am composing an Email in the native Mac.app in OSX Mojave.

I drag the image and as soon as the image is dragged the whole text-area turns grey and becomes unresponsive:

[image]

The image I wanted to drag is [this](http://res.cloudinary.com/mediacloud/image/upload/v1461000913/bexfxto3mbfceclq58td.png)

Comment: What happens when you merely attach the image to the email rather than dragging?

Comment: Wondering if you've figured this out.